# the vscode python extension has many activation events. But I don't want to use some of them, so what should I do to ban thes auto executed functions

Tags: visual-studio-code

"""

the vscode python extension has many activation events. But I don't want to use some of them, so
what should I do to ban thes auto executed functions ?

"""
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I55R5.png

Comment: if you don't use them they will not bite you, they are not auto-execute, it means that the extension should be activated if any of these events happen

Answer (score 0):

Those are optional setting that would “auto execute,” if you enabled them.

If you would like to see if you have any turned on, check your settings and search for any of the offending save actions